# How can I encode all text that a Python program outputs?

Tags: python, encode, final, translate, output

My friend is trying to make a program, and he wants it to be able to switch between outputting normal text and text encoded with Rot13 based on wheather an int variable is set to `0` or `1`. We've tested using `"text".encode('rot13')` and that works to encode the text, but there has to be an easier way to make anything the program outputs encode with rot13 than wrapping every instance of text output with `if 0, output text, if 1, output rot13 text`.

I was hoping there would be some sort of encoding that I could just wrap around all the code to make it work, but I tried searching online and couldn't find anything. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried monkey-patching `stdout`?

Comment: How is the text being output?  With `print`?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect output like so:

```
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout

class MyOut(object):
    def write(self, string):
        # Do what ever you want with the string
        old_stdout.write(string.upper())

    def flush(self):
        pass

sys.stdout = MyOut()

print "Hello world!"
```

Script above will give you `HELLO WORLD!` output.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest **not monkey patching `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`**, It's a bad practice as it can break other modules that you're using, or other modules that use your code.

A much safer approach is to use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#module-logging) module's [StreamHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) in conjunction with the [codecs module's encoded writer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.getwriter) to print encoded messages to the default `stdout` or `stderr` handler:

```
import logging
# import codecs # not necessary, this is embedded in logging
# import sys # not necessary, this is embedded in logging


# get your encoding flag here... 
flag = 1

# Log everything, and send it to stderr.
# create an encoded streamhandler with encoding based on flag
if flag == 1:
    writer = logging.codecs.getwriter('rot13')(logging.sys.stderr) 
    streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(stream = writer)
else:
    streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler() # defaults to unencoded stderr
# you can use sys.stdout instead,
# it depends on preference and use case

# set the log level threshold
streamhandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create a basic logger
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log.addHandler(streamhandler)

# now, instead of print, use log.debug(message)
print 'hello world'
log.debug('hello world')
```

The advantage of using the logging module is that it also allows you to set your own custom formatters and filters as well as get meaninful debug messages using `log.exception(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Just override `sys.stdout`.

```
import sys

# Save the original stdout
original = sys.stdout

# Create our own stdout
class writer(object) :
    def write(self, text):
        # Do encoding here
        #text = rot13encode(text)

        original.write(text)

# Override stdout with our stdout
sys.stdout = writer()

# print as usual
print "Hello"
```